# Obtain text within sections

Tags: r

this is my text:

```
Title
1 First section
1.1 Introduction1
Hello. My name is John. I am an under graduate student. I live in the U.S. I am majoring in computer science. Blah blah blah.
1.2 Another Intro
My last name is Doe. Blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence.
2 next section name
2.1 Random Section name
Blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence. Another random sentence.
Another random sentence. 
2.2 Requirements
The requirements include:
1. blah blah
2. blah blah blah
3. another random sentence
3 Third section
Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah.
4 End
```

I want to create a data frame that looks like:

```
Section Name            String

1 First section      
1.1 Introduction1       Hello. My name is John. I am an under graduate student. I live in the U.S. I am majoring in computer science. Blah blah blah.
1.2 Another Intro       My last name is Doe. Blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence.
2 next section name 
2.1 Random Section name Blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence. Another random sentence.
2.2 Requirements        The requirements include:
                        1. blah blah
                        2. blah blah blah
                        3. another random sentence
3 Third Section         Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah.
4 End
```

So basically, I want to create a data frame that has two columns: a column with
the section number and name, and a column with everything that comes after that section til the next section number.

Comment: That seems like an awful format. Why would you want to do that? It might be worth rethinking your data generation process; I would recommend storing data in a format more suitable for parsing and whatever down-stream analysis you'd like to do.

Comment: Share your approach?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is not failsafe against various formatting options or "strange" strings. It also uses some workarounds to make your text easier to parse. You might have to tune / play around with the regex depending on your input. Furthermore, below approach may certainly be improved concerning speed. However, it should, at least, provide you with an idea how to approach your problem.

```
txt = "Title
1 First section
1.1 Introduction1
Hello. My name is John. I am an under graduate student. I live in the U.S. I am majoring in computer science. Blah blah blah.
1.2 Another Intro
My last name is Doe. Blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence.
2 next section name
2.1 Random Section name
Blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence. Another random sentence.
Another random sentence. 
2.2 Requirements
The requirements include:
1. blah blah
2. blah blah blah
3. another random sentence
3 Third section
Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah.
4 End"

library(stringi) # use stringi since it accepts lookbehind of variable length
# turn bullet point into non digit form 
# here only a replacement, this might be done in a more sophisticated way keeping numbering information
txt = stri_replace_all_regex(txt, "\n\\d\\. ", "-BP:")
# remove trailing digits from words
txt = stri_replace_all_regex(txt, "(?<=( \\w{1,50}))\\d", "")
# split by new section / line
txt = unlist(stri_split_regex(txt, "\n(?=\\d)"))
# initialize new data.frame to store information
my_text = as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA_character_, 2*length(txt)) ,nrow = length(txt))
                        ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(my_text) = c("section", "text")
for (i in 1:nrow(my_text)) {
  # use positive lookbehind to find start of pattern marking a section 
  # and split there into section name and text
  # note that you might needto increase the maximum of 100 characters for the lookbehind,
  # to my knowledge you cannot simply use `+` but need to set a limit 
  out = unlist(stri_split_regex(txt[i], "(?<=(\\d[\\.\\d\\s|\\s][A-Za-z ]{1,100}))\\n"))
  my_text[i, "section"] = out[1]
  if (length(out) == 2) {
    my_text[i, "text"] = out[2]
  }
}

# for checking results only print first 50 characters
apply(my_text, 2, function(x) substr(x, 1, 50))
#      section                   text                                                
# [1,] "Title"                   NA                                                  
# [2,] "1 First section"         NA                                                  
# [3,] "1.1 Introduction"        "Hello. My name is John. I am an under graduate stu"
# [4,] "1.2 Another Intro"       "My last name is Doe. Blah blah blah blah. Another "
# [5,] "2 next section name"     NA                                                  
# [6,] "2.1 Random Section name" "Blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence. Anot"
# [7,] "2.2 Requirements"        "The requirements include:-BP:blah blah-BP:blah bla"
# [8,] "3 Third section"         "Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah."              
# [9,] "4 End"                   NA
```